# Reaper auto panning based on conditions

Tags: reaper, panning

I am currently evaluating Reaper v6.08 and I wonder if it's possible to pan based on certain conditions.

**Detailed explanation:**

- I have two tracks, A and B.
- A is panned 100% Left
- B is panned 100% Right

When both tracks have a certain amount of silence, in this short period of silence I want to flip Left and Right smoothly.

This means that track A must be panned from 100% Left to 100% right and track B vice versa.

The 'flipping' should take as much time as there is silence on both tracks.

Is something like this possible?

Please see screenshot that I created to explain...

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Fairly confident this is possible through the scripting interface of Reaper.